# Vectorize pandas df operation?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's say I have a numpy df such as

```
X = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
[  9.,   12.,   4.],
[  1.,  31.,   3.],
[  6.,   4.,  1.]]) )
```

I want to divide each entry by the row sum * column sum.  I know I can get row and column sum, respectively, using `X.sum()` and `X.sum(1)` but I don't know how to do the operation I'm seeking aside from looping through each entry brute force.

Answer (score 1):

Use broadcasting:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

X = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    [9., 12., 4.],
    [1., 31., 3.],
    [6., 4., 1.]]))

X_arr = X.values
mult = X_arr.sum(1)[:, None] * X_arr.sum(0)

result = X / mult
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
          0         1         2
0  0.022500  0.010213  0.020000
1  0.001786  0.018845  0.010714
2  0.034091  0.007737  0.011364
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to divide twice:

```
# axis='rows' divide row-wise
x.div(x.sum()).div(x.sum(1), axis='rows')
```

Output:

```
          0         1         2
0  0.022500  0.010213  0.020000
1  0.001786  0.018845  0.010714
2  0.034091  0.007737  0.011364
```